# How to download multiple links in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

How can I download the images from a cell which are separated by `;` character?

Here is an example cell (A2):

```
https://lh6.ggpht.com/uxLXvxuncWOm2mgU3ChtdGZ0eMp_WJTD4xrVxAKqCJMiR5ibaBbw-VUPJPjcGiqIDRbm=h310; https://lh3.ggpht.com/N7B7AVDDD0577crgHxHHo15uCkjSr3oimEwZWhF-VVxNYhRMIHd2eoI14WfuTHfMmtNC=h310; https://lh6.ggpht.com/c_pfo3A3fQh40udcyhdgGIVsBa_GB9A09O642Vlwi6ka4fqwyT9044pzU-jF_rjb4VX_=h310; https://lh5.ggpht.com/KqUgPKrZYuVa_AAOLtR0URf_8pJ_lX6au7UH2pcHzs7G3eLL9Vt7hAk83JgkqVMBIQ=h310; https://lh6.ggpht.com/uxLXvxuncWOm2mgU3ChtdGZ0eMp_WJTD4xrVxAKqCJMiR5ibaBbw-VUPJPjcGiqIDRbm=h900; https://lh3.ggpht.com/N7B7AVDDD0577crgHxHHo15uCkjSr3oimEwZWhF-VVxNYhRMIHd2eoI14WfuTHfMmtNC=h900; https://lh6.ggpht.com/c_pfo3A3fQh40udcyhdgGIVsBa_GB9A09O642Vlwi6ka4fqwyT9044pzU-jF_rjb4VX_=h900; https://lh5.ggpht.com/KqUgPKrZYuVa_AAOLtR0URf_8pJ_lX6au7UH2pcHzs7G3eLL9Vt7hAk83JgkqVMBIQ=h900
```

There are so many cells in A column which contains image links like this one. 
How can I save those images to a local folder?

It will be great if images rename to their URL, for example: The first image in cell A2:

```
uxLXvxuncWOm2mgU3ChtdGZ0eMp_WJTD4xrVxAKqCJMiR5ibaBbw-VUPJPjcGiqIDRbm.png
```

I've tested this VBA script:

```
Sub Save_image()
Dim oHTTP As Object
Dim sDestFolder As String
Dim sSrcUrl As String
Dim sImageFile As String

sDestFolder = "C:\Users\adale\Desktop\Compendium Images\"
sSrcUrl = ActiveCell.Value
If Left(sSrcUrl, 2) = "//" Then
    sSrcUrl = "https:" & sSrcUrl
End If

sImageFile = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - InStrRev(ActiveCell.Value, "/"))
Debug.Print sImageFile
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = sImageFile


Set oHTTP = CreateObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "GET", sSrcUrl, False
oHTTP.send

Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
oStream.Open

oStream.write oHTTP.responseBody
oStream.savetofile sDestFolder & sImageFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite

Set oStream = Nothing
Set oHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

But it returns an error on this line:

```
oHTTP.Open "GET", sSrcUrl, False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Split()` method and use `;` as the delimeter, then use a `For Each` loop to run a block of code for each URL:

```
'// Create single dimension array of image URLs
myImages = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ";")

For Each img In myImages
    '// Do whatever you want with each image URL here...
    '// If there are spaces inbetween then perhaps use Trim(img)
Next

'// Rest of code...
```

Comment: Should I change sImageFile with myImages function ?
Could you please update your answer specifically for my question ?

Comment: The answer does specifically address your question, just change `sImageFile` to `myImages` which is an array, then loop through that array and use the `img` variable.